# Refresh 2 materialized view one after another oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where in i will be using a materialized view in another materialized view joins. So i need the MV to be refreshed before it is used in join. How do i make second MV refresh after first MV is finished?

Comment: What causes the first MV to refresh?  Is it refreshing on commit?  On a schedule?  As part of a custom job?

Comment: Both are schedule based.